# Make path with RMShape and RMMapView

Tags: ios, dictionary, path, annotations, mapbox

I implementing map application using mapbox sdk. I need to show marker and path together, I google around but still not get main idea to do this.

So far I have done...

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)aMapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation {

RMMarker *marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-blue.png"]];
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {
    if ([annotation.annotationType isEqualToString:@"marker"]) {
        [marker replaceUIImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_marker.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(32, 48)]];
        [marker setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1)];
        return marker;
    } else if ([annotation.annotationType isEqualToString:@"path"]) {
        path.lineWidth = 3;
        for (int i=0; i<[myCoordinateArray count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"my coord count : %d", [myCoordinateArray count]);
            CLLocationCoordinate2D myLoc = [[myCoordinateArray objectAtIndex:i] coordinate];
            if (i>0) {
                [path addLineToCoordinate:myLoc];
            } else {
                [path moveToCoordinate:myLoc];
            }
        }
        [path closePath];
        return path;
    }
} 
return nil;
```

}

//Add annotation

```
myPin = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
        [myPin setMapView:mapView];

        [myPin setCoordinate:myLatLng];
        [myPin setTitle:@"Marker"];

        myPin.annotationType = @"marker";
        [mapView addAnnotation:myPin];
        [mapView setNeedsDisplay];

myPath = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
        [myPath setCoordinate:myLatLng];
        myPath.annotationType = @"path";
        [mapView addAnnotation:myPath];
```

Did I do something wrong, or Did i miss something? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your second code block, you don't need the calls to `setMapView:` or `setNeedsDisplay`.

Second, what is not working about this? The code looks like it should work and show both a point and a path on the map.

Comment: Thank you, Now I can manage it to work. I just miss something which i not know. Anyways, Thank you very much.

Comment: @majorl3oat could you please update your question to reflect what you were missing ? 
I'm currently facing the same issue and can't seem to solve it!
Thanks

Comment: @Priest really sorry, It's been a long time ago, I cannot remember how did I solve that. Now I was move to another project.

Comment: @Priest, if you solved this problem share it please xD

Comment: @NilsHolgerson what I actually ended up doing was going through the MapBox code and tinkering with their already subclassed MapView classes. The whole process turned out to be such a hassle that we had to eventually abandon the idea all together :\